# ASUS X551M won't come on and does not charge too

Tags: laptop, usb-flash-drive, power

My ASUS X551M shut down itself and won't come on. It does not even take power when i plug in charger. 
It shut down itself when i plugged in a flash drive in one of the ports which i later realized is having a virus(i mean the flash). 
Can you please help me cuz it's a brand new laptop and did not use it for over a month.
Kindly help me out.

Comment: No lights? No fan movement? Does the charging light on the charger itself come on?

Comment: I think it needs to drain the residual charge, 
 unplug everything connected to the laptop, then unplug the battery along with the AC charger.
Now, press and hold the power button for 30-45 seconds, after that put back the battery and plug the AC charge on. Then turn on your laptop, see if it'll work again.

Answer (score 1):

The solution iSR5 gave WORKS!

I just fixed the same problem. I was simply watching a video and the computer just shut off like it was shocked or something. It wouldn't turn on after holding down the power button nor was the light on at the bottom left of the laptop indicating charging.

I took out all the screws on the bottom of the laptop and opened it by taking a small Flathead screwdriver and etching it all around the sides. The top layer of the keyboard came off. BE VERY CAREFUL WHEN YOU DO THIS. There are 3 strips connected to the bottom half of the laptop that are connected to the top keyboard layer. The strip connecting the power button came off while I was removing the battery. I just stuck it back in and clamped down the white clamps and it stayed in.

After lifting directly up on the battery it came out. I unplugged the power adapter also. I then held down the power button for 60 secs to be extra sure; thus draining the residual charge. I then proceeded to place the battery back in(battery still had some charge). I held/pressed the power and it turned back on. I was so relieved that it worked.